# Migrating Winston Logger from 2.4.4 to 3.x... The new transports have me lost

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

So I'm trying to migrate from Winston 2.x to 3.x, however it comes with a rather large shift in setting up the transports and I can't seem to get it working how I had it setup before, let alone improve on it for that matter.
What I want in console

```
[human-readable-date] [level(colourised)] : [text string], [formatted JSON]
```

In 2.4, I had it printing the JSON out, unformatted and that was enough but improvements are always nice.

This was my old config file

```
const winston = require("winston");
require("winston-mongodb");
const config = require("./mongoDb").config;
const url = config.URL;

const tsFormat = () =>
  `${new Date().toLocaleDateString()} ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}`;

const logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      timestamp: tsFormat,
      colorize: true
    }),
    new winston.transports.MongoDB({
      timestamp: tsFormat,
      db: url,
      level: "debug",
      autoReconnect: true
    })
  ]
});
module.exports = logger;
```

--EDIT--

This is where I'm at currently

```
const winston = require("winston");
require("winston-mongodb");
const config = require("./");
const mongo = require("./mongo");

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.colorize(),
        winston.format.timestamp({
          format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
        }),
        winston.format.align(),
        winston.format.printf(
          info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`
        )
      )
    }),

    new winston.transports.MongoDB({
      db: `${config.mongoURI}/${config.mongodb}`,
      level: "debug",
      tryReconnect: true,
      storeHost: true
    })
  ]
});
module.exports = logger;
```

But I can't get the desired JSON part working at all, or get it being sent to mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achieved similar results to my prefered local styled [`pino-pretty`](https://github.com/pinojs/pino-pretty).

Was able to print out error stacks and additional metadata objects.

**Code:**

> I added an additional custom field for a namespace because my app creates a child logger for each file rather then exposing the "root" logger using `logger.child({ label: namespace })`

```
winston.format.combine(
  winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }),
  winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
  winston.format.colorize(),
  winston.format.printf(
    ({ timestamp, level, label, message, stack, ...rest }) => {
      const namespace = label ? `(${label})` : ''
      const errStack = stack ? `\n${stack}` : ''
      const meta =
        rest && Object.keys(rest).length
          ? `\n${JSON.stringify(rest, undefined, 2)}`
          : ''
      return `[${timestamp}] ${level}: ${namespace} ${message} ${meta} ${errStack}`
    }
  )
)
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Honestly I'd given up and had stuck to 2.X! Thanks for this, I'll test it in my next project